# Android Data Binding Library lambda for custom Listener

Tags: android, lambda, binding, listener

**This code works just fine:**

Adapter code:

```
@BindingAdapter({"app:onClick"})
public static void setOnClick(My view, View.OnClickListener onClickListener)
{
   view.addOnClickListener(onClickListener);
}
```

Xml code:

```
app:onClick="@{ (v) -> view.onClick(v) }"
```

**But I need to make custom listener like this:**

Adapter code:

```
@BindingAdapter({"app:onClose"})
public static void setOnClose(My view, My.OnCloseListener onCloseListener)
{
   view.addOnCloseListener(onCloseListener);
}
```

Xml code:

```
app:onClose="@{ (x, y) -> view.onClose(x, y) }"
```

Listener code:

```
public interface OnCloseListener
{
    void onClose(My x, int y);
}
```

**In this case the application does not compile(not big suprise :( ), is it even possible to use lambda with custom listener?**

Comment: What does the compilation error say?

Answer (score 2):

It is OK with gradle 2.2.0 version:

```
public interface ITest {
    void apply(String apply);
}
```

```
@BindingAdapter({"test"})
public static void testAdapter(View view, ITest test){
}
```

```
public interface IViewModel extends Observable {
    void accept(String string);
}
```

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.example.mvvm.IViewModel"
            />
    </data>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:test="@{vm::accept}"
        />

</layout>
```

Maybe that was an older version of data-binding library, which cause your error.